# C# - trying to cast from double to int, but failing

Tags: c#, casting

I try to pow a number with 2. I wrote:

```
int xy = y - x;
double xx = (double)xy;
distance = Math.Pow(xx, (double) 2.0);
```

`x`, `y` are integers.

I getting this error:

> cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'int'. An explicit
>   conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Why is that error? Both params are `double` typed.

The error red line drawn below this code: 
`Math.Pow(xx, (double) 2.0);`

Comment: Your title was wrong. You're trying to cast from `double` to `int`, not the other way around.

Comment: fyi you con't need to cast `xy` to `double`, `int` is implicitly convertible to `double`.  You can just pass `xy` right to `Math.Pow`.  You also don't need to cast the literal `2.0` to `double`.  Literal numbers with a decimal in them are already of type `double`.  Of course, none of this is related to the answer.

Comment: @xxbbcc you are right, it should be named ```xxbbcc``` ;)

Comment: @NavidVafaei :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this;

```
int xy = y - x;
double xx = (double)xy;
double distance = Math.Pow(xx, (double)2.0);
```

Because in this case `Math.Pow` returns `double`. From metadata;

```
public static double Pow(double x, double y);
```

Comment: Oh, damn .. I forgot that I've set distance as int >< thank you sir!

Answer (score 9):

I guess `distance` is declared as `int`

```
 distance = (int)Math.Pow(xx, (double) 2.0);
```

Answer (score 2):

> Why is that error?

Because [Math.Pow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.pow.aspx) returns **double** and you're trying to assign it to a variable (`distance`) which has **int** type.

When converting double precision floating point number (**double** type) into integer (**int** type) you're loosing information. That's why compiler doesn't allow implicit conversion and therefore throws that error message you posted above. In this situation you have to tell compiler you're aware of potential information loss and you do that by applying explicit casting:

```
int distance = (int)Math.Pow(xx, (double)2.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

2.0 is already `Double`. Seems like distance is `int`

```
 distance = (int)Math.Pow(xx, 2.0);
```